# Define array keys and values in php

Tags: php

I want to array fetch the keys and values from database table and I need it to add it in array. So how can I set it to array? If I use array_push() then it will start index from 0, and I need array index which is fetched from table.

My table is named **array_val**

**Key**    **Value**
k1     val1
k2     val2

Comment: and where are those codes?

Comment: You might want to look into redesigning that DB of yours, since the EAV-pattern is generally considered to be an anti-pattern. If you post more details about your database, and the data stored in it, we might be able to help you with a better solution.    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: For PHP 5.5+ [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can also be used. Check 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array_val = array();

$results = mysql_fetch_array($query);
foreach($results as $key => $val){
    $array_val[$key] = $val

}
```

Comment: This works for me, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` if you are using MySQLi.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what the author asks about, as he's using an EAV-table.

Comment: @ChristianF Haha, my bad, I've no clue what an EAV-table is. Where did he mention he was using it?

Comment: If you look at the example "data" he's posted, you'll notice that there are two columns. One of which contains the "key" and the other the "value". I've added a link to Wikipedia in my comment to the question, which explains the EAV-pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much @ChristianF :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ //list of sql results
$my_array[$row["key"]]=$row["value"];
}
```

**key** and **value** is your table fields. Table is : **array_val**

Comment: This! This is the right one

Answer (score 0):

May below code can help you out

Simply, use `while` loop and create array elements from db records.

```
$arr = array();

$sql = "SELECT key,value FROM <tablename>";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $arr[$row['key']] =  $row['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that ought to be `$arr[ $row['key'] ] =  $row['value']`